# I cant connect to aws postgres rds from mattermost ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to install mattermost on ec2 instance but mattermost can't ping my rds instance.

Here is my mattermost config

```
"SqlSettings": {
        "DriverName": "postgres",
        "DataSource": "postgres://username:password@site.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/mattermost?sslmode=disable\u0026connect_timeout=10\u0026binary_parameters=yes",
        "DataSourceReplicas": [],
        "DataSourceSearchReplicas": [],
        "MaxIdleConns": 20,
        "ConnMaxLifetimeMilliseconds": 3600000,
        "ConnMaxIdleTimeMilliseconds": 300000,
        "MaxOpenConns": 300,
        "Trace": false,
        "AtRestEncryptKey": "1ekbsxs1rs96gfffctc1xm317sw9r4rn",
        "QueryTimeout": 30,
        "DisableDatabaseSearch": false,
        "MigrationsStatementTimeoutSeconds": 100000,
        "ReplicaLagSettings": []
    },
```

postgres port 5432 is opened

I have tried to connect to the postgres instance using pgadmin which works fine.

Error

```
{"timestamp":"2023-07-24 10:10:55.707 Z","level":"info","msg":"Pinging SQL","caller":"sqlstore/store.go:238","database":"master"}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-24 10:10:55.720 Z","level":"error","msg":"Failed to ping DB","caller":"sqlstore/store.go:248","error":"pq: no pg_hba.conf entry for host \"172.0.0.0\", user \"postgres\", database \"mattermost\", no encryption","retrying in seconds":10}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-24 10:11:05.721 Z","level":"info","msg":"Pinging SQL","caller":"sqlstore/store.go:238","database":"master"}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-24 10:11:05.732 Z","level":"error","msg":"Failed to ping DB","caller":"sqlstore/store.go:248","error":"pq: no pg_hba.conf entry for host \"172.0.0.0\", user \"postgres\", database \"mattermost\", no encryption","retrying in seconds":10}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly configured your security groups?

1. Create a VPC security group (or use the default security group)for your postgres rds instances to be in, assuming the ID is **sg-1234567**
2. Create a VPC security group for your EC2 instance (mattermost host) to be in,  assuming the ID is **sg-abcdefg**
3. Create a custom rule in the **sg-1234567**
   to allow connections from the **sg-abcdefg** for your EC2 instance.

after these steps, you should see an Inbound rule in **sg-1234567** like this:
[image]

you can follow [this document from aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html)

if the problem is not fixed, try to find clues in this [trouble shooting document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html#USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.Troubleshooting)

Good Luck!